# Android: updating widget using alarmmanager

Tags: android, android-widget, alarmmanager

I have an app with a widget. In order to update the widget, I use the following code:

```
private void scheduleNextUpdate(Context context, boolean fail) {
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetProvider.class);
    intent.setAction(ACTION_SCHEDULED_UPDATE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
    Calendar nextSchedule = Calendar.getInstance();

        **nextSchedule.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));**
        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        nextSchedule.set(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DATE),0,0,10);
        nextSchedule.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

    **alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextSchedule.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);**
}
```

Sometimes it updates around midnight as expected, sometimes it updates around 2-3 am (GMT related) and sometimes it just doesn't update at all and I need to remove the widget and place it again.

What am I doing wrong? How can I be sure that the update is done around midnight based on the device timezone it's on? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Possible it's because background restrictions. 
Why not to use ScheduledTask or WorkManager?

Comment: In what way they are better than AlarmManger? I ask because when developing the widget, I read that alarmmanager should be used for this.

Comment: Yesterday the widget was updated at 2am, exactly as my GMT, meaning this is not a doze issue. Before setting utc timezone, I had the same problem and UTC fixed it, now it's back. I wonder if removing it again, will again "fix" it.